# Get all the dates of current week

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0, datetime-format

Say I consider Sunday - Saturday as a week, how do I get all the dates of the current week in c#?

For example, current date is `30th March 2017`, the output I need is,

```
26-March-2017,
27-March-2017,
28-March-2017,
29-March-2017,
30-March-2017,
31-March-2017,
01-April-2017
```

Comment: Have you attempted this? Show source code of your attempt. This isn't an ask and thou shall receive website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try `DateTimeFormat` to find out current week's starting date and *Linq* to generate the string:

```
  DateTime startOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(
      (int) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - 
      (int) DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);

  string result = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(0, 7)
    .Select(i => startOfWeek
       .AddDays(i)
       .ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")));
```

In case of `en-US` culture you'll get (week starts from *Sunday*)

```
26-March-2017,  // <- starts from Sunday
27-March-2017,
28-March-2017,
29-March-2017,
30-March-2017,
31-March-2017,
01-April-2017
```

In case of, say, `ru-RU` culture you'll get (week starts from *Monday*)

```
27-марта-2017,  // <- Starts from Monday
28-марта-2017,
29-марта-2017,
30-марта-2017,
31-марта-2017,
01-апреля-2017,
02-апреля-2017
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming  that Sunday will be the start day of the week, as it is mentioned in the question I suggest following solution.

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date; // This can be any date.

Console.WriteLine(today.DayOfWeek);

var day = (int)today.DayOfWeek; //Number of the day in week. (0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday... and so On)

Console.WriteLine(day);

const int totalDaysOfWeek = 7; // Number of days in a week stays constant.

for (var i = -day; i < -day + totalDaysOfWeek; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(today.AddDays(i).Date);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this [here](https://luofuboblog.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/get-start-and-end-date-of-current-week-or-month-c/)

```
 DayOfWeek Day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
 int Days = Day - DayOfWeek.Monday; //here you can set your Week Start Day
 DateTime WeekStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Days);
 DateTime WeekEndDate1 = WeekStartDate.AddDays(1);
 DateTime WeekEndDate2 = WeekStartDate.AddDays(2);
 DateTime WeekEndDate3 = WeekStartDate.AddDays(3);
 DateTime WeekEndDate4 = WeekStartDate.AddDays(4);
 DateTime WeekEndDate5 = WeekStartDate.AddDays(5);
 DateTime WeekEndDate6 = WeekStartDate.AddDays(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, an extension method is the most useful approach:

```
  public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDatesOfWeek(this DateTime date, CultureInfo ci) {
     Int32 firstDayOfWeek = (Int32) ci.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
     Int32 dayOfWeek = (Int32) date.DayOfWeek;
     DateTime startOfWeek = date.AddDays(firstDayOfWeek - dayOfWeek);
     var valuesDaysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<Int32>();
     return valuesDaysOfWeek.Select(v => startOfWeek.AddDays(v));
  }
```

Use as follows:

```
     DateTime myDate = DateTime.Today;
     IEnumerable<DateTime> result = myDate.GetDatesOfWeek(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
     foreach ( DateTime d in result ) {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
     }
```