# Get the date of the start week of a given date c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to get the start of the week from a given date. For example if i passed in a DateTime of 16/08/2018 i would expect a return of 13/08/2018. Everything i have found is to find the start of the current week.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all the dates of current week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122759/get-all-the-dates-of-current-week) Replace the current Date with whatever date you want.

Comment: Once you have a `DateTime` then you have its `DayOfWeek` property.  Once you have that then you can determine how many days prior is the "first" day of that week.  What have you tried?

Comment: Using `DateTime.DayOfWeek` would give you the information you need to make the calculation. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199080/how-to-get-the-integer-value-of-day-of-week) for details on using `DayOfWeek`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the DateTime for the start of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039/how-can-i-get-the-datetime-for-the-start-of-the-week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

Parse the date from string to DateTime object (if required)

Add days current day of the week * -1 (turn it negative) + 1

```
string s = "2018-08-23 13:26";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime startOfWeek = dt.AddDays(((int)(dt.DayOfWeek) * -1) + 1);
Console.WriteLine(startOfWeek);
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mmNIc1)

---

Edit: If you are bothered about the sunday going to the next Monday,
then change the Sunday to remove 7 days from the current date like so;

```
string s = "2018-08-17 13:26";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

bool isSunday = dt.DayOfWeek == 0;
var dayOfweek = isSunday == false ? (int)dt.DayOfWeek : 7;

DateTime startOfWeek = dt.AddDays(((int)(dayOfweek) * -1) + 1);
Console.WriteLine(startOfWeek);
```

Comment: If you run that with August 19th, it returns August 20th.

Comment: i would be passing in dates from monday to friday (working days). So returning the following monday from the sunday wont affect me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version gives you the monday of the week (assumes that weeks start on monday and end on sunday)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startOfWeek = dt.AddDays((((int)(dt.DayOfWeek) + 6) % 7) * -1);    
Console.WriteLine(startOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Monday and Sunday of the week with date variable.
Can easy try with date variable.

````cs
DateTime date = new DateTime(2019, 12, 1);
int day = (int) date.DayOfWeek;
DateTime Monday = date.AddDays((-1) * (day == 0 ? 6 : day - 1));
DateTime Sunday = date.AddDays((1) * (day== 0 ? day : 7 - day)); ```
````

Comment: Please add some explanation to improve your answer, and so others can understand *how* this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Super Simple!
You can use the DayOfWeek to get how far back you have to go.
More info [Is avaliable here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Sundays are 0, Mondays are 1.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now; //gets current time
int day = date.DayOfWeek; //gets current day
DateTime Sunday = date.AddDays( (-1) * day ); //go back all the days to get to Sunday
DateTime Monday = date.AddDays( (-1) * (day - 1) ); //go back all the days - 1 to get to Monday
```

As pointed out by a comment this doesn't work if the current day is on a sunday...
So the Monday fix is:

```
DateTime Monday = date.AddDays( (-1) * (day == 0 ? 7 : day - 1) ); //go back all the days - 1 to get to Monday
```

Comment: @mjwills the previous monday, we are "adding" a negative number there, hence we are going back on the timeline.

Comment: Yeah... the edge case of where the current day is on a sunday makes my approach add 1 day instead of substracting 6.
Nothing a simple ``day == 0 ? 7 : day`` wouldn't solve :D

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! Guess i should have taken more than a minute to think of the reply :D